# saving records with cakephp-mongo plugin

Tags: cakephp, mongodb, cakephp-2.0

I am using cake 2.0 with the Mongo Plugin from ichikaway. Mongo version 2.0.2. I am unable to save records to Mongo from my cake app

My database set up is:

```
public $mongo = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'blog',
    'port' => 27017,
    'prefix' => '',
    'persistent' => 'true'
);  
 }
```

I have tried numerous variations on the examples provided on the plugins github page for my model but to no avail. Apparently I don't need to specify $useTable = false; in the model with the latest version of the plugin - but if I don't I get a missing table error...

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

school boy error on my part, just needed to cd into the plugin/Mongodb directory and then

```
git checkout -b cake2.0 origin/cake2.0
```

which will load the cake 2.0 version of the plugin.

Facepalm.